# Push Notification message not received in App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Request notification in the APPID configure button generate both development and production files.
Download this two file installed and generate pem file. I put these file into the Application.

while am testing time Application received notification but i published app in App-store.i downloaded the Application am not able to receive notification. in the php file device token is differ from development.

Please advise me to solve this problem.

With Regards,
Senthilkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use the production url instead of the dev url to send your push messages?
production: ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2195
developement: ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

Comment: Thanks for your idea., But we put same ssl links into the sever side and also the sever side message sent response received.But not receive client side notification message.